# Is anything known about $\Delta_n$ bounding?

Tags: lo.logic, reverse-math, nonstandard-analysis, theories-of-arithmetic

For a class $\Gamma \in \{ \Sigma_n, \Pi_n, \Delta_n \}$ in the arithmetical hierarchy, we can consider the induction, bounding, and least number principles for $\Gamma$:

- $\mathsf{I}\Gamma$ is $\big[ \varphi(0) \land \forall x \big( \varphi(x) \to \varphi(x+1) \big) \big] \to \forall x\ \varphi (x)$ for every $\varphi \in \Gamma$.
- $\mathsf{B}\Gamma$ is $\forall u \big[ \big( \forall x < u\ \, \exists y\ \, \psi(x,y) \big) \to \exists v\ \, \forall x < u\ \, \exists y < v\ \, \psi(x,y) \big]$ for every $\psi \in \Gamma$.
- $\mathsf{L}\Gamma$ is $\exists x\ \varphi (x) \to \exists x' \big( \varphi (x') \land \forall y < x'\ \, \lnot \varphi(y) \big)$ for every $\varphi \in \Gamma$.

(Yes, I know $\Delta_n$ formulae aren't really a thing, but for the purposes of this question, let's say $\Delta_n$ formulae are the $\Sigma_n$ formulae that are equivalent to a $\Pi_n$ formula).

Over $\mathsf{PA}^- + \mathsf{I}\Sigma_0$, Kirby and Paris [1] proved several equivalences:

- $\mathsf{L}\Sigma_n$, $\mathsf{L}\Pi_n$, $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_n$, $\mathsf{I}\Pi_n$ are all equivalent;
- $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_{n+1}$, $\mathsf{B}\Pi_n$ are equivalent;
- $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_{n+1} \implies \mathsf{B}\Sigma_{n+1} \implies \mathsf{I}\Sigma_n$, and these implications are strict.

Over $\mathsf{PA}^- + \mathsf{I}\Sigma_0 + \mathsf{exp}$, Slaman [2] proved (building on results of Kirby and Paris) that  $\mathsf{L}\Delta_n$, $\mathsf{I}\Delta_n$, $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_n$, are all equivalent.

This puts the principles into two equivalence classes: $\{ \mathsf{L}\Sigma_n, \mathsf{L}\Pi_n, \mathsf{I}\Sigma_n, \mathsf{I}\Pi_n \}$ and $\{ \mathsf{I}\Delta_n, \mathsf{L}\Delta_n, \mathsf{B}\Sigma_n, \mathsf{B}\Pi_{n-1} \}$.

---

However, in all of this, nothing has been said about $\mathsf{B}\Delta_n$, and I couldn't find any results relating $\mathsf{B}\Delta_n$ to the other principles. **Is anything known about $\mathsf{B}\Delta_n$**?

---

[1] L. A. S. Kirby and J. B. Paris. *$\Sigma_n$-collection schemas in arithmetic.* Angus Macintyre, Leszek Pacholski, Jeff Paris (eds.), *Logic Colloquium '77* (proceedings of colloquium held in Wrocław, August 1977). Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics **96**, pp. 199-209. Elsevier North-Holland, NY, 1978.

[2] Theodore A. Slaman. *$\Sigma_n$-bounding and $\Delta_n$-induction.* Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society **132(8)**, pp. 2449-2456, 2004.

Comment: Since $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_n \Rightarrow \mathsf{B}\Delta_n \Rightarrow \mathsf{B}\Pi_{n-1}$, these three are actually equivalent.

Comment: Slaman`s paper is available at https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-08/S0002-9939-04-07294-6/S0002-9939-04-07294-6.pdf.

Comment: Slaman’s result was improved by Neil Thapen: the schemata are already equivalent over $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$; in fact, $I\Delta_0+\forall x\,\exists y\,y=x^{\alpha(x)}$ suffices with $\alpha$ being the inverse of any increasing primitive recursive function (growing arbitrarily fast). See https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/186/1/89106/a-note-on-delta-1-induction-and-sigma-1-collection .